# Create Selenium Grid Server in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes-helm, selenium-grid

I want to install Selenium Grid in Kubernetes. I am new to this. I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/README.md) for installing the helm chart and I am getting below output:

[image]

However, when I try to access `http://selenium-grid.local` mentioned in the output from browser I am getting
selenium-grid.local’s server IP address could not be found.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there are any additional steps that needs to be followed to access grid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing wrong, you have to use the **ingress** and expose the URL that you are trying to access.

Check if ingress is set or not

```
kubectl get ingress
```

if not check accordingly and get URL or **ingress controller** setup first and expose the **service** of **Selenium gird** with ingress which will resolve your issue.

you will be able to access it.

Read my similar answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68264859/5525824